# Concurrency error when working with arraylist of sprites

Tags: android, concurrency

Currently, I'm elaborating with game development, and have created (with help of some online tutorials) following sample game. The goal is to touch the sprites on the screen and thus killing them (i.e. they are removed from the screen). Screenshot is following

[image: screenshot]

When I *kill* few of them, I get following exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  277): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
E/AndroidRuntime(  277): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):        at cz.trada.gd101.GameView.draw(GameView.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime(  277):        at cz.trada.gd101.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:32)
```

The source code is shown bellow. Unfortunately, I don't know how to highlight the exact lines of codes here on SO, so I put following comment in front of them: `//ERROR COMING`
So, you can easily locate those lines.

**Please, help me to understand the cause of the concurrency error and find a solution.**

P.S. The picture resources `my_sprite_girl` and `my_sprite_boy` used in the game are attached at the end of this post.

**Main.java**

```
package cz.trada.gd101;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(new GameView(this));
    }
}
```

**GameView.java**

```
package cz.trada.gd101;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
    private static final String TAG = "GameView";
    SurfaceHolder holder;   

    GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
    List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();

    long lastClick;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                boolean retry = true;
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        gameLoopThread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }   
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                createSprites();
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameLoopThread.start();             
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                    int height) {
            }
        }); 

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
//ERROR COMING
                sprite.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 500) {
                 lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 float x = event.getX();
                 float y = event.getY();
                 synchronized (getHolder()) {
                     for (int i = sprites.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                         Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);
                         if (sprite.isCollision(x, y)) {
                             sprites.remove(sprite);
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                 }
          }
          return true;
    }

    private void createSprites() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.my_sprite_girl));
            sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.my_sprite_boy));
        }
    }

    private Sprite createSprite(int resource) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);
        return new Sprite(this, bmp);
    }
}
```

**GameLoopThread.java**

```
package cz.trada.gd101;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;

public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {
    private static final String TAG = "GameLoopThread";
    private static final int FPS = 10;

    private GameView view;
    private boolean running = false;

    public GameLoopThread(GameView view) {
        this.view = view;       
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        while (running) {
            Canvas c = null;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();                 
            try {
                c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                synchronized (view.getHandler()) {
//ERROR COMING
                    view.draw(c);                   
                }
            } 
            finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }

            sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            try {
                if (sleepTime > 0)
                    sleep(sleepTime);
                else
                    sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**

[image: my_sprite_girl]

[image: my_sprite_boy]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error probably comes from the call to `remove()` in `onTouchEvent()` while the loop in `draw()` is iterating over the sprites.

If your `Sprite` class already has `equals()` and `hashCode()` (or you add them), you could use [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) instead which gives you lock-free `contains`, `remove` and `add` operations in log(n).

[`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) would probably also solve the problem but not be very performant (due to copy-on-write part).

As a style note, you could also use an `Iterator` and its `remove()` method in the `onTouchEvent()` loop:

```
Iterator<Sprite> it = sprites.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Sprite sprite = sprites.next();
    if (sprite.isCollision(x, y)) {
        it.remove();
        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: `ConcurrentSkipListSet` is available in API 9 and higher, so what to do in case of lower versions? My latest idea is just set a *flag* saying the klicked sprite is dead in the touch event method, and than in the draw method in GameView where I iterate through sprites to decide if I want to call its draw method (sprite.isDead() == false) or to remove it from the sprites List (when sprite.isDead() == true). However, I'm not sure this is right idea, because it feels like I put some logic in the draw method that should be used for drawing objects only. Don't know what to do.

Comment: The flagging sounds like a good workaround if you need to support API levels <9 -- be careful to make the flag field `volatile`, though, so changes are visible across thread. You could also try to port `ConcurrentSkipListSet` to your API level, the fundamental `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package is there since API level 1.

Comment: I just checked, you can get a clean compile of `ConcurrentSkipListSet` on API level 7 by copying around `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, `ConcurrentNavigableMap`, `NavigableMap`, `NavigableSet` and `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` and removing the `clone()` method in `ConcurrentSkipListSet` --- but I think your dirty flag workaround is much nicer than this :)